# Send multiple value on android google analtics library

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to add multiple value and in my code.

My code is:

```
 mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("send")
            .setAction("event")
            .setLabel(key)
            .setValue(value)
            .build());
```

Comment: https://benwilcock.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/event-tracking-with-analytics-api-v4-for-android/

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you wanted multiple values needs to be sent for one key while tracking the event.

If that is the case use the **StringBuilder** class to prepare the String value by concatinating the multiple string values.

Ex: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append("StringValue1");

sb.append("StringValue2");

pass sb.toString() inplace of your value.

Comment: unfortunately value must be long

Comment: How about converting long to String like   String.valueOf(longValue)

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append(String.valueOf(longValue1));

sb.append(String.valueOf(longValue2));